# IBM MQ transmit queue messages not placed on dead letter queue

Tags: ibm-mq

I currently have an XMIT queue with a SDR channel pointed to a QREMOTE. In a  scenario where either the local or remote channels are down, I would like to forward the messages on the XMIT queue to the DLQ. It appears that in this scenario, messages remain on the XMIT queue until the channel is reestablished. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: What is the reason you want it on the DLQ vs the XMITQ waiting for the remote queue manager to be up again?

Comment: I'd be curious to know the reason why too.

Comment: @JoshMc Separate parties control the sending and receiving. The messages need to be sent within a certain time limit. The sending side would like their application to monitor one place for errors.

Comment: Normally you would monitor for "aged" messages on the XMITQ, and you can also monitor the channel for issues.  MQ will generate channel events if enabled for when the channel status changes, monitoring software can alert when a channel goes into RETRYING or STOPPED status so you know that there is an issue.

Comment: @JoshMc It looks like I'll be able to figure something out with channel events, thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking not.  From an ibm red paper: http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redpapers/pdfs/redp0021.pdf

> A transmission queue is a local queue with the USAGE(XMITQ) attribute
>   configured. It is a staging point for messages that are destined for a
>   remote queue manager. Typically, there is one transmission queue for
>   each remote queue manager to which the local queue manager might
>   connect directly. If the destination is unavailable, messages build up
>   on the transmission queue until the connection can be successfully
>   completed. Transmission queues are transparent to the application.
>   When an application opens a remote queue, the queue manager
>   internally creates a reference to the relevant transmission queue and
>   messages are put there.